# Trying to make my own string class

Tags: c++, class, compilation, g++

These are the errors I'm getting for my program.

```
myString1.cpp: In constructor ‘MyString1::MyString1(char*, int)’:
myString1.cpp:6: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
myString1.cpp:6: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
myString1.cpp: In member function ‘MyString1 MyString1::append(MyString1)’: 
myString1.cpp:11: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the ‘&’ ?) 
myString1.cpp: In member function ‘void MyString1::clear()’:
myString1.cpp:25: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token 
myString1.cpp:25: error: expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token
myString1.cpp:25: error: expected `;' before ‘{’ token 
myString1.cpp: In member function ‘bool MyString1::empty()’:
myString1.cpp:29: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
myString1.cpp:31: error: expected primary-expression before ‘else’ 
myString1.cpp:31: error: expected `;'  before ‘else’
```

And here is my program in the three different parts.

myString1.h

```
#ifndef MYSTRING1_H
#define MYSTRING1_H

class MyString1
{
  private:
   char chars[];
   int size;
  public:
   MyString1();
   MyString1(char chars[], int size);
   MyString1 append(MyString1 s);
   char at(int index);
   int length();
   void clear();
   bool empty();
   int find(char ch);
};
#endif
```

myString1.cpp

```
#include "myString1.h"
using namespace std;

MyString1::MyString1(char chars[], int size)
{
  this->chars[] = chars[];
  this->size = size;
}
MyString1 MyString1::append(MyString1 s)
{
  for(int i = size; i > size - s.length; i++)
    chars[i] = s.at(i);
}
char MyString1::at(int index)
{
  return chars[index];
}
int MyString1::length()
{
  return size;
}
void MyString1::clear()
{
  size = 0;
  chars[] = {};
}
bool MyString1::empty()
{
  if(chars[]){
    return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
}
int MyString1::find(char ch)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    if(chars[i] = ch)
      return i;
}
```

testMyString1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myString1.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  MyString1 first("cat", 4);
  MyString1 second("dog", 4);
  cout << first.at(1) << " and " << second.at(1) << endl;
  first.append(second);
  cout << first.at(6) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Im a newbie just trying to learn how to use the g++ compiler so just looking for some help reading the error messages and debugging my code.  Also I'm sure there is some very bad code so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: `char chars[];` <-- Whats wrong with this?

Comment: this->chars[] = chars[] <--- and this.

Answer (score 4):

The code has a lot of mistakes so I don't know where to start from but I suppose that generally giving you some pointers to help you with understanding your code would be okay.

In my opinion you don't need to have a size index in a String class since there is the strlen() function that will gladly compute it for you.
Now for your class declaration check how you declare the pointer that will hold the string for you. You need to do it like below:

```
class MyString1
{
  private:
   char* chars;//this declares a pointer to a char that will hold the string for you
  public:
  ...
```

Also you are never allocating the char* that holds the strings. Your constructor should be:

```
MyString1::MyString1(const char* chars)
{
  this->chars = (char*) malloc(strlen(chars)+1); //this will allocate an array of strlen() chars +1
  strcpy(this->chars,chars);
}
```

As you can see I am not using a size index since strlen can quite efficiently find that out for you. +1 is for the '\0' that signifies the end of a string.

Now to append something to the string, that's gonna be tricky.

```
void MyString1::append(const MyString1& s) //it's good to give a constant reference to the string here
{
  //first of all we gotta reallocate the pointer,since we don't have enough memory for the string
  int newsize = strlen(this->chars) + strlen(s)+1;
  this->chars = (char*) realloc(this->chars,newSize); \\ no check for realloc failure, I know but this is just an example

  strcat(this->chars,s.chars);

}
```

You don't need to return anything when you append. You are doing something to THIS string.

Your ::at() function is almost okay. Imagine though what would happen if the size of the string was 10 and you request MyString1::at(12). This would probably cause a Segmentation fault (that's not good).

So you should alter your code to do bounds checking like below:

```
char MyString1::at(int index)
{
  //if it's out of bounds let's return -1 which will signify that we got an out of bounds value  (could also throw an exception here but that's a different subject altogether)
  if(index > strlen(this->chars) || index <0)
      return -1;

  return chars[index];
}
```

Also in C/C++ you have to free the memory that you allocate. So in order to do that you should declare something called a *destructor*

```
MyString1::~MyString1()
{
  free(this->chars);
}
```

Finally the is empty function can just be like that:

```
bool MyString1::empty()
{
  return (this->chars[0] == '\0';
}
```

Comment: +1 for a good answer. But it's really better to keep track of the current size rather than invoke `strlen()` in `empty()` and for every reallocation.

Comment: always depends on your system and requirements. I have my own String implementation for my projects and I do it without keeping size of the string as a separate variable and for my requirement the performance is really good. But that's a different topic altogether. Should discuss it, somehow in a question, would love additional insight on the matter

Comment: malloc() requires you to check that it worked (it may return NULL).

Comment: `strlen()` is relatively expensive - it needs to scan along the entire string until it hits the 0, so string classes intended to be of general utility do invariably keep track of it. Even without though, `empty()` can simply `return this->chars[0] == '\0';`. And, the functions as presented aren't `const` correct: the constructor and append operator should accept constant strings to copy from. The Standard Library `std::string` has an at() which throws an exception - I'd recommend that, especially as `char` may be unsigned and impossible to differentiate from a -1 value in the string.

Comment: yes and I did note that I was not checking for either malloc or realloc correctness because that would be out of the scope of the answer. 

@Tony Delroy will fix the const correctness and your suggestion for the empty function

Comment: Will edit malloc also since I wrote it in C style but needs a cast for C++.

But guys really do you actually check after every malloc in your code? Seriously? The case that malloc fails is really destructive and either means system memory failure or some kind of memory corruption.

Comment: As for keeping the size I am willing to accept that you are most probably right and that for the general case it might be better especially in a Unicode class where you have to parse in a very specific way.

Hey now that I think of it I know what the next change to my String implementation should be. Always made me feel uneasy knowing I parse the UTF-8 each time to find the String length. Just did not want to get around to actually changing the whole code. Some good insight from the community helps change that :)

Comment: @Lefteris re `malloc` - I generally avoid it in favour of `new` and consequent exceptions.  Of course, that doesn't work terribly well either - OSes can return virtual address space but exhaust memory when attempting to allocate the physical after a fault.  No good way to handle memory exhaustion, but with lots of swap the performance often provokes and grants time for some scythe work on over-indulgent processes.

Comment: Ye I see what you mean. Of course in C++ new should be preferred over malloc. Most of my code being in C I am using only malloc. And as you say memory exhaustion is a very tricky case that is never easy to handle